# RIA EntityQuery duplicating rows where one of the values matches

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria

In my app I perform an entityquery.  If I use SQL profiler, catch the SQL query that is generated, and run it manually, it gives the results I expect.
For instance

```
Val     Date
68  2011-05-31 00:00:00.000
48  2011-05-30 00:00:00.000
92  2011-05-29 00:00:00.000
52  2011-05-28 00:00:00.000
32  2011-05-27 00:00:00.000
32  2011-05-26 00:00:00.000
52  2011-05-25 00:00:00.000
81  2011-05-24 00:00:00.000
```

If I stick a breakpoint in my code and look at what the LoadOperation.Entities contains, I notice that when the 'Val' figure for an entry has already appeared (I.E like 52 above), then the LoadOperation.Entities collection uses the data from the previous entry (with a value of 52), rather than the actual date.
So in the data above, my LoadOperation.Entities looks like (note that dates are now repeated, seemingly because the 'Vals' have occurred previously)

```
68  2011-05-31 00:00:00.000
48  2011-05-30 00:00:00.000
92  2011-05-29 00:00:00.000
52  2011-05-28 00:00:00.000
32  2011-05-27 00:00:00.000
32  2011-05-27 00:00:00.000
52  2011-05-28 00:00:00.000
81  2011-05-24 00:00:00.000
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

My EntityQuery looks like

```
    var appDataQuery = context.GetVwKeyDatasQuery().Where(d => d.KPIDate <= OverViewDate && d.GELID == GelID && d.ClockworkID == ClockWorkID).OrderByDescending(d => d.KPIDate);
```

And this generates the correct T-SQL, which when executed in SQL Query Analyzer returns the correct values.

The rest of the code is

```
    LoadOperation lo = context.Load<vwKeyData>(appDataQuery);
    lo.Completed += new EventHandler(LoadOperation_Completed);
```

The EventHandler is

```
    public void LoadOperation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    LoadOperation<vwKeyData> histResults = sender as LoadOperation<vwKeyData>;
    int _count = 0;
    foreach (vwKeyData v in histResults.Entities)
    {.......
```

By this point histResults.Entities is already incorrect.  Any help would be appreciated as this is screwing up some charting stuff i'm working on.

Thanks

M

Comment: Manson, It might be because the data in being cached by EF.

Comment: Just figured it out.  In my model, the date field wasn't set as a key.  The other values in the row returned by the EntityQuery could quite reasonable have the same values.  The only one that's guaranteed to change is the date.  Once I set the date as a key, it started including the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as above.  Each column that is required to uniquely idenitfy a row, should be set as an Entity Key in the model.

(Right click the column in the model designer and select Entity Key).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the following.

```
context.vwKeyData.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

`OverwriteChanges` will make sure that the data is always loaded from the datasource.
This should help sort our your problem.

Comment: This isn't the solution in my case, but I wasn't aware of this option, so thanks anyway.